# Using property file vs Database table to store Locale specific data

Tags: java

We have a case where certain class has 4 property out of which one (description) is locale specific . Class is something like

```
Class Abc {
private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private String value;

}
```

For now, we have 3 of them in a database table, and description in a property file, where id is key and description is value.

We have roughly 800 data.

Recently, we have a requirement where we need to search this class based on their properties , mixed .

I was just thinking to move even the description in database tables, where we have locale specific tables. Any suggestions ?

Comment: There is the class ListResourceBundle, alternative to .properties, maybe as base class for a database based (cached) localisation.

Comment: Thanks  Joop Eggen, but how will it perform for searching ? specially when we have to consider starts with, ends with and contains like cases ?

Comment: I meant: use a database, but leave the resource bundles as-is, but now not PropertyResourceBundle but a child of ListResourceBundle, that loads its data from the database. However as a ListResourceBundle keeps all its strings in memory, a search could be programmed too. But a database is more versatile as it requires no programming to retrieve data.